# Do I have to define a js function before another function uses it if they are both enclosed in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    doAjax = function () {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html'
        })
        .done(onDone)
        .fail(onFail)
        .always(function () {
            ;
        });
    },
    onDone = function (data) {
        content = data;
        if (content.match(/^[eE]rror/)) {
            mvcOnFailure(content);
        } else {
```

I am getting errors with jslint saying things like "onDone" is used before it is defined. Is this something I should try to avoid, is this a problem. Note that both the doAjax and onDone functions are both enclosed inside another function.

Comment: That's because you haven't declared the variable with `var` keyword.

Comment: Sorry there was some code above this where the var keyword was used. The functions are declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define it like:

```
function onDone() {}
```

Then, you do not have to define it before you use it in the same scope because all function definitions like this are automatically "hoisted" to the top of the function and are defined before any code in that scope runs.

If you define it like:

```
onDone = function() {}
```

then, javascript respects the order you run your code and `onDone` does not have this value until that line of code is executed in the normal flow of of code execution in your function so this line would need to be executed before anything that uses `onDone` is called.

Comment: I was declaring all the functions as variables like this:  var x = function () {}, var y = function () {} etc.  So are you saying that if I do it this way I may have problems with the order of the declarations?  Are there any disadvantages in declaring the way you suggested? Thanks

Comment: @SamanthaJ - I know of no disadvantages to declaring them as `function onDone() {}`. You can't use that form for a method assignment, but it works for regular functions.

Comment: Sorry to be asking so many questions. But can you explain what you mean by "You can't use that form for a method assignment"? In my code I use the onDone function as a parameter in my ajax call. Will that be a problem ?

Comment: @SamanthaJ - Method definitions have to be of the form: `obj.method = function() {}` or `obj.prototype.method = function() {}` so they always involve an assignment.